# Rxjs throw timeout error from pipe to observable error section

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6, redux-observable

I'm trying to throw timeout error from the observable pipe to the observer as an error but I am still getting the timeout error in the val callback (in subscribe) while I want to get it in the error callback:

For who is experimented, you can test this code easly and edit it in stackblitz in this link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-eegqyz?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

```js
of(4000, 3000, 2000)
    .pipe(
        concatMap(duration =>
            makeRequest(duration).pipe(
                timeout(2500),
                catchError(error => {
                    //throwError('Valid token not returned');
                    return of(`Request timed out after: ${duration}`)
                })
            )
        )
    )
    .subscribe(
        val => console.log(val),
        error => console.log("error", error)
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I managed to solve it:

```js
of(4000, 3000, 2000)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(duration =>
      makeRequest(duration).pipe(
        timeout(2500),
        catchError(err => throwError(`Request timed out after: ${duration}`))
      )
    ),
  )
```

So, basically you have a way to handle errors that come from `timeout`(which is why you were getting the error in the first cb from `subscribe()`) and now if throw another error(using `throwError`), there is no other place to handle the incoming errors, so you will get the error in its callback(from `subscribe()`).

[Here is a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pz4brf?file=index.ts).